# Element Screenshot in Selenium (python, ChromeDriver) is cut off at bottom for vertically tall element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screenshot

Trying to screenshot an element but the element is vertically tall and it's getting cut off at the bottom.
Seems to happen any time I try to screenshot a tall element.

Selenium 4 with python 3.11.6 on Windows 10.

Is this a limitation of `element.screenshot()`? Or am I missing something? Couldn't find anything in docs or web search.

Tried this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options_ = webdriver.ChromeOptions().add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options_)
driver.get("https://afd.calpoly.edu/web/sample-tables")
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content > table:nth-child(17)")
element.screenshot("out.png")
driver.close()
```

Expect the whole element to be captured but instead it gets cut off at the bottom.

Here's what gets captured:

[image: screen capture of element]

Here's the full element that should be captured it seems to me (I zoomed it out so I could take a manual screenshot to show):

[image]